# Mean imputation/estimation of missing data

Tags: mean, missing-data, data-imputation

Could someone please refer me to papers that have imputed the mean to missing values of a continuous variable? (i.e. papers that have used mean imputation)

I have imputed my missing IMD values using the mean value and I want to see examples of other **papers that have used mean imputation** as well.

Comment: Don't do that.  It's a bad idea.  See [this](http://missingdata.lshtm.ac.uk/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&id=7&Itemid=96) for a short overview.

Comment: I know it's not recommended but I would like to see some papers nevertheless who have done it, just to examine good and bad practice. if you know of any please let me know, thanks. Would you say complete case analysis is better practice? thanks

Comment: Here is a reference (review in the BMJ) on imputation which recommends not doing that: **http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2714692/**

Comment: This article talks quite a bit about mean imputation, so perhaps it refers to some papers while on the subject: http://wiki1.math.yorku.ca/images/6/6d/Enders_jofschoolpsyc.pdf